# change stage size to fit window resize without scaling

Tags: jquery, easeljs

I am adopting easeljs from raw canvas programming, one feature that 
has me stuck is how to resize the stage when the browser window resized.

I just listen to the resize event of the window and change the canvas size
accordingly, I have simplified the example to cover the complete window.

```
  // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
  function resizeCanvas() {
    $('#canvas').width($(window).innerWidth());
    $('#canvas').height($(window).innerHeight());
    renderBoard();
  }
  resizeCanvas();
  $(window).on('resize', resizeCanvas);
```

and for this example, my renderBoard() function contains

```
  function renderBoard() {
    let centerCircle = new createjs.Shape();
    centerCircle.graphics.beginStroke("red")
      .drawCircle(canvas.clientWidth / 2, canvas.clientHeight / 2, 4);
    let playingRect = new createjs.Shape();
    playingRect.graphics.beginFill("green")
      .rect(10,10, canvas.clientWidth-20,canvas.clientHeight-20);

    stage.addChild(playingRect,centerCircle);
    stage.setChildIndex(playingRect, 0);
    stage.update();
  }
```

my new render distorts and scales with the canvas, which I don't want. What is the correct way to resize the stage without scaling its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. **jQuery**

`jQuery.width()` (and `jQuery.height()`) implementation uses CSS styling to change the width of the element selected, which is not correctly interpreted by **easeljs**.

The solution was simply to direct change of the width of the element without using jQuery

change the line

```
$('#canvas').width($(window).width());
```

to be

```
$('canvas').get(0).width=$(window).width();
```